# SQL commands not working in C# (ASP.NET web forms)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

I'm having a trouble with my code.
I'm trying to have the user the ability to submit his email to subscribe to my "notify me" service, I havn't code anything lately so I a bit confused..

I'm trying to Insert, Read, and Update data in my Online SQL Server.. but nothing seems to work! I don't know why I tried everything I know I check a million times it seems good.
Plus if there is any errors my catch should show it to me but even that doesn't work :(

Take a look at this maybe your eyes will see something I don't see.

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["notifyCS"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            conn.Open();
            try
            {
                string checkEmail = "SELECT User_Email FROM tbl_users WHERE User_Email = @User_Email";
                string checkSubscription = "SELECT User_Status FROM tbl_users WHERE User_Email = @User_Email";
                string submitEmail = "INSERT INTO tbl_users (User_UID, User_Email, User_Status) VALUES (@User_UID, @User_Email, @User_Status)";
                string submitEmail2 = "UPDATE tbl_users SET User_UID = @User_UID, User_Status = @User_Status WHERE User_Email = @User_Email";
                SqlCommand emailCMD = new SqlCommand(checkEmail, conn);
                SqlDataAdapter emailSDA = new SqlDataAdapter
                {
                    SelectCommand = emailCMD
                };
                DataSet emailDS = new DataSet();
                emailSDA.Fill(emailDS);
                //if there is no email registered.
                if (emailDS.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
                {
                    SqlCommand registerEmail = new SqlCommand(submitEmail, conn);
                    string User_UID = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "").ToUpper();
                    registerEmail.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User_UID", HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(User_UID));
                    registerEmail.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User_Email", HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(email.Text));
                    registerEmail.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User_Status", HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("subscribed"));
                    registerEmail.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    registerEmail.Dispose();
                    conn.Close();
                    conn.Dispose();
                    email.Text = null;
                }
                else if (emailDS.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    using (SqlCommand checkSub = new SqlCommand(checkSubscription, conn))
                    {
                        checkSub.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User_Email", HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(email.Text));
                        SqlDataReader sdr = checkSub.ExecuteReader();
                        if (sdr.HasRows)
                        {
                            string res = sdr["User_Status"].ToString();
                            if (res != "subscribed")
                            {
                                using (SqlCommand registerEmail2 = new SqlCommand(submitEmail2, conn))
                                {
                                    string User_UID = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "").ToUpper();
                                    registerEmail2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User_UID", HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(User_UID));
                                    registerEmail2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User_Email", HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(email.Text));
                                    registerEmail2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User_Status", HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("subscribed"));
                                    registerEmail2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                    registerEmail2.Dispose();
                                    conn.Close();
                                    conn.Dispose();
                                    email.Text = null;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                conn.Close();
                                conn.Dispose();
                                Response.Redirect("index.aspx");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
                if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    conn.Close();
                    conn.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Suggested reading: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/), [it's evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/).

Comment: If you debug through it, does `emailDS` get filled up correctly?

Comment: I would expect that you have an error on the line that has `emailSDA.Fill(emailDS);`, because this is expecting a parameter for `@User_ID` that is never assigned to the select command. At which point you will enter your catch block, write the message to the response and silently fail.

Comment: *I havn't code anything lately* - good moment for an upgrade then; using EF would boil that lot down into about 5 lines of code.. `var x = emails.FirstOrDefault(..); if(x == default) emails.Add(...) else x.Blah = ...; SaveChanges()`

Comment: *I didnt add any parameters to the checkEmail string* - But that usually results in an exception "Must declare the scalar variable @x" i think.. I thought you said there were no errors.. Anyhow, you fixed it with some rubber duck debugging :D nice one

Comment: @Larnu will do, thanks!

Comment: @GarethD I didnt add any parameters to the checkEmail string, so thanks I will and check again

Comment: @CaiusJard Can you give and source with learing for that?

Comment: For learning EF https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/ is a reasonable start point. Beware there are two main flavors, and if your project is old asp net webforms and on net framework you might want EF6 (efcore apparently works but I don't think I ever did it). Most new dev is net core (razor pages is the closest to webforms i think) and correspondingly EFCore..

Comment: @CaiusJard I just upgraded my vs form 2019 to 2022 so i guess there is a lot of bugs and issues but still there was no errors for me

Comment: @CaiusJard thanks

Comment: I added a parameter to the first block but still nothing happend and the catch didnt catch anything

Comment: I forgot to mention that breakpoints doesn't work at all.

Comment: You do not have to HtmlEncode parameter values that you send to the database

Comment: In the interest of saving world poverty and that of writing too much code? See my approach below - you save a few keyboards here.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            conn.Open();
            string checkEmail = "SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE User_Email = @User";

            SqlCommand emailCMD = new SqlCommand(checkEmail, conn);
            emailCMD.Parameters.Add("@User", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = email.Text;

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(emailCMD);
            SqlCommandBuilder daU = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);

            DataTable emailRecs = new DataTable();
            emailRecs.Load(emailCMD.ExecuteReader());

            DataRow OneRec;
            if (emailRecs.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                OneRec = emailRecs.NewRow();
                emailRecs.Rows.Add(OneRec);
            }
            else
            {
                // record exists
                OneRec = emailRecs.Rows[0];
            }
            // modify reocrd
            OneRec["User_UID"] = User_UID;
            OneRec["User_Email"] = email.Text;
            OneRec["User_Status"] = "subscribed";
            email.Text = null;
            da.Update(emailRecs);
            }
        }
```